# Integration with vanishing differential form on a domain

Tags: integration, differential-forms

Although it is a very simple question, but let me check my understand.
The question is: Do we get zero if we integrate a differential form on a domain where the form vanishes?

Here is a simple example:
Let us consider a differntial form $\omega$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and choose normal coordinates $(x,y,z)$:
$$\omega \equiv dz \wedge dy  - y^4 dx \wedge dy$$

The domain is the intersection $D:(z = x y^4) \cap (x^2 + y^2) \leq r^2$, for some positive constant $r$.

Hence everywhere on this domain $\omega =0$.

Then if we consider the integration of $\omega$ on $D$, I think I will get zero:
$$\int_D \omega =0.$$

Is this correct? Actually, I'm worry about whether $\omega =0$ or not on the boundary $\partial D$.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Of course, $\omega=0$ at boundary points as well (on the entire tangent space). If you restrict a $2$-form to the boundary (a $1$-dimensional manifold), it's automatically $0$ no matter what!

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you! Your comment is very helpful for me.